# DataTextField and DataValueField properties of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every one says that, you have people in your database and in this case the `DataValueField` can be the `ID` of the `person` and the `DataTextField` can be the name of the `person` in your `DropDownList`.

But I want to know that if I don't have any `ID` type field then what will be my  `DataValueField`?

Column in my database are `UserName`, `Password`, `UserType`.
What will be my `DataTextField` & `DataValueField`?

Comment: What's your table's Primary Key?

Comment: As @S.Akbari says you should have a primary key. But you can use the same field for both text and value, like UserName.

Comment: UserName is Primary Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, Set "UserName" to both DataValueField and DataTextField.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not mean that you should have a field named `Id` but you need a field that has a unique value. So the Primary Key is the best option for it whether its named Id or anything else.

As the UserName is the Primary Key so you can use it as the DataValueField.